# Is there a command to list all the kubernetes cluster's configuration files

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have a Kubernetes cluster using Istio and I need to debug an issue. I need to see all the configuration files that are being used. I would like to delete certain configurations from my cluster, but I am not sure what is running.

So for example, I can deploy a configuration
`kubectl apply -f config1.yaml`

I need a list of all of the deployed configuration like "config1". Is there is a command that exists and can someone please provide it.

Comment: In this context, config1 is probably a folder containing one or more kubernetes yaml files. You would need to know which type of object you are looking for.

Comment: @coderanger In this context, I should have written kubectl apply -f config1.yaml

Comment: What kind of object is in it?

Comment: The kinds that are defined in some my Yaml files are Gateways, Services, VirtualServices. I would like to know all applied yaml files.

Comment: Just guessing, maybe `kubectl gel all --all-namespaces=true -o yaml` could do it.

Comment: @whites11 That does help me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of Istio, and applied to routing/networking, there are 6 objects:

```
# kubectl api-resources | grep networking.istio
destinationrules                  dr           networking.istio.io            true         DestinationRule
envoyfilters                                   networking.istio.io            true         EnvoyFilter
gateways                          gw           networking.istio.io            true         Gateway
serviceentries                    se           networking.istio.io            true         ServiceEntry
sidecars                                       networking.istio.io            true         Sidecar
virtualservices                   vs           networking.istio.io            true         VirtualService
```

So, to get all Istio objects, you can do:

`kubectl get dr,envoyfilters,gw,se,sidecars,vs -oyaml -n NAMESPACE`

Or `--all-namespaces`